# Count distinct records in a JOINed SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables with a 1-many relationship, Device and TestResult.

My application has a filter builder front-end that allows a user to retrieve TestResults based on whatever filters they specify. This generates queries similar to this:

```
SELECT d.id,
       d.serialNumber,
       d.createdAt,
       r.id,
       r.testBlockId,
       r.deviceId,
       r.type,
       r.fieldResponses,
       r.stationName,
       r.summary,
       r.createdAt
FROM Device AS d
INNER JOIN TestResult AS r ON r.deviceId = d.id
WHERE d.id IN
    (SELECT id
     FROM Device
     WHERE serialNumber BETWEEN '000000001000' AND '000000002020'
     ORDER BY serialNumber ASC
     LIMIT 570, 10)
  AND r.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-03-27T11:54:43.100Z' AND '2020-04-01 09:21:02.362768'
ORDER BY serialNumber ASC;
```

This query limits the number of Devices returned, which handles paging on the front-end. I'm also generating a query that counts the total number of Devices that match the filters, without the OFFSET and LIMIT values. This is used to tell the front-end how many pages of records there are.

If I simply run the above query but change the SELECT statement to `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.id) as totalDevices` and remove the LIMIT, it's very slow. So instead I'm generating this query to find the count:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.id) AS totalDevices
FROM Device AS d
INNER JOIN TestResult AS r ON r.deviceId = d.id
WHERE serialNumber BETWEEN '000000001000' AND '000000002020'
  AND r.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-03-27T11:54:43.100Z' AND '2020-04-01 09:21:02.362768';
```

This query runs faster, but it still isn't fast. I'm wondering if there is a better way to retrieve a count of the distinct Device records that would be returned from this query.

This query shows the following execution time with 1,000,000 records:

```
Run Time: real 8.090 user 1.562500 sys 6.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the query to use a GROUP BY instead of a COUNT DISTINCT, which has sped up the execution time.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalDevices
FROM (
  SELECT d.id
  FROM Device AS d
  INNER JOIN TestResult AS r ON r.deviceId = d.id
  WHERE serialNumber BETWEEN '000000001000' AND '000000002020'
    AND r.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-03-27T11:54:43.100Z' AND '2020-04-01 09:21:02.362768'
  GROUP BY d.id
);
```

This query shows the following execution time with 1,000,000 records:

```
Run Time: real 3.433 user 0.953125 sys 2.484375
```

The COUNT DISTINCT query shows the following execution time:

```
Run Time: real 8.090 user 1.562500 sys 6.500000
```

So the GROUP BY query takes just under half of the time of the COUNT DISTINCT query.